# Is probability always rational?

Tags: probability

Probability is the the number of favourable events divided by the number of total events. Since it is an integer divided by an integer, it should always be rational. So why do we say, for instance, that the probability of landing a small object inside a circle enclosed by a square is $\frac{\pi}{4}$? It may be the limit of the probability as the number of events is increased, but the probability has to be rational no matter how many events are conducted.

Comment: Because "number of favourable events divided by number of total events" only works in a context where only finitely many outcomes are possible.

Comment: Further, the "number of favorable events divided by number of total events" works only in the context of where each outcome is equiprobable.  The more general definitions lie in measure theory and need not be so restrictive.

Comment: Your first sentence is a description of only the very simplest examples of probability, it is not a "definition" of probability. Start digging a little deeper into probability. You will start encountering many examples of probability that do not fit the pattern of those very simplest examples.

Comment: To emphasize my earlier point again, one of my favorite examples is "When you play the lottery, you either win or you lose, but the probability of winning is generally not going to be $\frac{1}{2}$"

Answer (score 2):

A probability can take any value from $0$ to $1$, even an irrational once. You can empirically estimate an event's probability from a finite dataset, but don't let the estimate always being rational mislead you! There is some error in any such estimate, and an error bar around a rational number contains both rational and irrational numbers.

You've already noted a probability equal to $\pi/4$. [Here's one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle) that's $2/\pi$. [Here's another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#Probability_of_coprimality) that's $6/\pi^2$. These results can even be used to estimate $\pi$, although it's not very accurate without an enormous dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Probability measures uncertainty.  The probability of an event is between 0 and 1.  However, only in special situations is probability  the number of favorable events divided by the number of total events.  All outcomes in the sample space would need to be equally likely (and there would need to be a finite number in the sample space) for this definition of probability to hold.